# Using select2_from_ajax with a JSON datasource

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-backpack

I am new to Laravel and to Backpack for Laravel so please bear with me.  I am trying to create a client registration form that features a "State" field which is populated dynamically depending on the value selected for the "Country" field.

I am following the instructions provided by Backpack's author here: https://backpackforlaravel.com/docs/3.5/crud-fields#select2_from_ajax

Both states and countries come from this dataset:   https://github.com/antonioribeiro/countries.  They are returned as collections but they are not read from the DB.

#### Table schema for Clients (simplified)

```
+-------------------+---------+--------+
| Field             | Type    | Length |
+-------------------+---------+--------+
| uuid              | CHAR    | 36     |
| name              | VARCHAR | 128    |
| city              | VARCHAR | 128    |
| state             | VARCHAR | 64     |
| country_iso_cca2  | VARCHAR | 2      |
+-------------------|---------+--------+
```

#### The good part

The "Country" field works just fine.  It fetches data from the JSON dataset at creation and reads/writes info from or to the DB on update/save:

```
// ClientCrudController.php

$countries = new Countries();
$allCountriesCodes = $countries->all()->pluck('name.common', 'cca2')->toArray();

$this->crud->addField([
    'name' => 'country_iso_cca2',
    'label' => 'Country',
    'type' => 'select2_from_array',
    'options' => $allCountriesCodes,
    'allows_null' => false,
    'default' => 'US',
]);
```

#### The bad (incomplete) part

```
// ClientCrudController.php

$this->crud->addField([
    'name' => 'state',
    'label' => 'State',
    'type' => 'select2_from_ajax',
    'entity' => 'foobar', // the method that defines the relationship in your Model
    'attribute' => 'name',
    'data_source' => url('api/states'),
    'placeholder' => 'Select a country first...',
    'dependencies' => ['country_iso_cca2'],
]);
```

Calling `/admin/client/create` will result in an error (*"Call to undefined method App\Models\Client::foobar"*).

I understand that the error is raised because there is no model defined for States and hence no relationship.  My problem is, I do not understand what the implementation is supposed to look like in a case like this where the two select fields do not represent separate entities at an ORM level.

Is it possible to implement this kind of dependency in a "backpack-native" way, without resorting to creating a custom field type?

Comment: Hmm... how about if you replace ```foobar``` with ```state``` in your addField() statement?

Comment: @tabacitu In that case, I get _"Call to undefined method \App\Models\Client::state()"_